# How to make a Swift Dictionary that hold specific values?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Usually I create my swift dictionary like so:

```
var myDict: [String: String]
```

But how do I create a Dictionary that can have as values, only a String or a Bool?

If I declare the dictionary like the following code

```
var myDict: [String: Any]
```

then my array would now be able to hold any object which I do not want. Is there any way to declare the Dictionary to only accept `String` and `Bool` value types?

**[EDIT] -**
Use case is: i need to have a dictionary of Keys and values. But i only want to values to be restricted to be either Strings or Bools. Nothing else. The goal is to eventually use this Dictionary to convert to a JSON format to send to some server.  Based on the answers below, are my only options either enums or classes/structs? I was wondering if there was a way to make the Bool and the String conform to some protocol?

The idea is to maybe declare the Dictionary like so

```
var myDict : [String: stringOrBool]
```

And to fill in the dictionary like this

```
myDict["firstKeyStringValue"] = "my first string value" // This should work
myDict["firstKeyBoolValue"] = true // This should work
myDict["someOtherKey"] = 123 // This should fail
```

**Edit 2** 
Based on the answers below i chose the protocol approach because it was easier on the syntax. But as Catfish mentioned below in the comments, it may take up a bit more memory.

Comment: Consider to use a custom `struct` or `class` rather than a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is your use case? We may be able to suggest a better design pattern all together.

Comment: @davecom Use case is i need to have a dictionary of Keys and values. But i only want to values to be restricted to be either Strings or Bools. Nothing else. The goal is to eventually use this Dictionary to convert to a JSON format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
protocol StringOrBool {
}

extension Bool: StringOrBool {
}

extension String: StringOrBool {
}

var myDict: [String : StringOrBool] = [:]

myDict["testKey"] = "sd"   // works
myDict["testKey2"] = false // works
myDict["testKey2"] = 2     // fails
```

Comment: Your solution is absolutely correct and you have my upvote. Just one suggestion: the name of the protocol should begin with an **uppercase** letter. So `StringOrBool` instead of `stringOrBool`.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like

```
enum StuffThatGoesInMyDictionary {
    case Text(String)
    case Boolean(Bool)
}
```

and then have your dictionary be

```
var myDict: [String : StuffThatGoesInMyDictionary]
```

Comment: ok, i am a little confused. i used that enum. then i did --> myDict["testKey"] = "testValue". But it gave me error "cannot assign value of type "String" to type "StuffThatGoesInMyDictionary". I am unfamiliar with that enum syntax. How do you use it?

Comment: Because you would to do : let foo = myDict["testKey"] then switch foo with 2 cases : .Text and .Boolean

Comment: Yeah, there's no automatic conversion. You need to check which of the possibilities a given value actually is, using a switch. Similarly, you need to construct one of the cases when putting one in, like myDict["testKey"] = .Text("hello")

Comment: @Catfish_Man: Very nice solution. Specifically because it does force you to choose one (and only one) type.

Comment: @Catfish_Man hi, based on the votes, it seems your answer (or `appzYourLife` generic answer) is correct. But, One last question, it looks like `pathTheCode`'s answer is easier to type. Is there any problems with his approach? If his answer is bad, I'll select yours as answer.

Comment: The protocol approach has some performance overhead ("existentials", i.e. variables with just a protocol type rather than a concrete type conforming to a protocol, take up a bit more memory), but should work fine. I'd say go with whichever one works best for you.

Comment: thanks man. Will use patches answer, as it is easier on the syntax when adding values to the Dictionary. But will certainly keep yours in mind. You already have my upvote. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

> This solution is based on the answer by *Catfish_Man*, I just made it generic.

With this enum

```
enum XORWrapper<A,B> {
    case Value0(A)
    case Value1(B)
}
```

you can declare a value that does wrap a value of 2 generic types (e.g. `String` and `Bool`).

```
let boolOrString: XORWrapper<String, Bool>
```

Then you can populate it with the first Type (e.g. a `String`)

```
boolOrString = XORWrapper.Value0("Hello world")
```

or with the second one (e.g. a `Bool`)

```
boolOrString = XORWrapper.Value1(true)
```

Comment: Hi, you answer seems a good generic version of catfish_man's. Would patchTheCode's answer be a bad one? I was considering it since its less code and adds values to the Dictionary using normal syntax, but im not sure if an extension will have bad side effects

Comment: @Jay: Both answers from *catfish_man* and *PatchTheCode* are correct so pick up the one you are most comfortable with.